# jQuery events after load page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-events

I have a cascade dropdownlist when the first change value the second change using `.change` event.
What I want is if the value of the selected item of the first dropdownlist was selected by default how to invoke the change of the second?
On resume how to bind the second dropdownlist on the first dropdownlist selected item not only on change event?

Comment: just call `.change()` after you've bound the event, e.g. `$('.ddlOne').change(function(){/*whatever*/}).change();`

Comment: @JohnRasch perfect it works just another detail I'm using that in a form and when the model is not valid the controller made a return View(model) and here I want the ddl to keep there old selected values, now it's ok the second ddl is bound to the first one but the selected value isn't, what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever it is you're doing when the first item is selected, do that on page load also.

For example:

```
$.ready(function(){
   doStuffOnIndexChange();
   $('selectOne').change(doStuffOnIndexChange);
 }
)

function doStuffOnIndexChange()
{
 // whatever you need to do here.
}
```

Or as John pointed out in his comment, fire the change event for the initial select item:

```
$('.ddlOne').change(function(){/*whatever*/}).change();
```

Comment: I tried the first proposition with $(document).ready and hadn't work will try with load thanks

Comment: @Yasminette Sorry, it was coding 3 things at once. I did mean to use the ready method, not load. I've updated my answer. What exactly happens when you do it this way? What error do you get?

Comment: there are no errors but the second ddl didn't bind